# Did the Saturn V have the status check "go at throttle up"?

Tags: saturn-v, ascent

I'm familiar with that shuttle [status check](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22278/space-shuttle-go-at-throttle-up), "go at throttle up." Did the Saturn V have the same, or similar status check vocalized during the ascent?  Did the Saturn V have to throttle down during Max-Q then throttle up afterwards?

Comment: It did not need to throttle down on Max-Q, see this: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/how-long-does-max-q-last
It did shut down one engine later than Max-Q, to avoid exceeding 4g:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#S-IC_first_stage

Comment: @FredLarson I guess Russell has now answered everything, including what I said in the previous comment :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Saturn V's first-stage engines don't throttle, so there's no "throttle bucket" and no "go at throttle-up" call. One of the first-stage engines is shut down late in the burn, but that's to limit maximum g-force for crew comfort, not for Q limiting.

[Maximum Q for the Saturn is about 33.8 kPa](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15461/195) and for [the shuttle it's 28.7 kPa](http://orbitalaspirations.blogspot.com/2018/05/max-q-and-dynamic-pressure.html). Compared to the shuttle, the Saturn V is aerodynamically pretty simple, and generally a little more robustly constructed; it just bulls through max Q instead of throttling back.

According to the [Apollo 11 Flight Journal](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/01launch.html), the progress calls during this early part of ascent were centered on the varying [abort modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_abort_modes) that were available. The closest thing to a "go at throttle-up" call might be CAPCOM telling them they're good at the 1-minute mark:

> 000:01:02 McCandless: Apollo 11, Houston. You're good at 1 minute.
>
> 000:01:06 Armstrong: Roger. [Long pause.]

Max Q for the Saturn-Apollo stack is at about 84 seconds into the flight; the crew and mission control don't acknowledge it, but the public affairs officer does on the public channel (no timestamp):

> PAO: We're through the region of maximum dynamic pressure now.

The next "go" call is at the 2 minute mark:

> 000:02:03 McCandless: Apollo 11, this is Houston. You are Go for staging. [Pause.]

Shortly after that we have:

> 000:02:17 Armstrong: Inboard cut-off.

The center engine of the 5 on the first stage is shut off here to hold acceleration down to 4g, for crew comfort. Dynamic pressure at this point is about 3.2kPa, only about 1/10th of max Q.

Comment: Thank you also for explaining the need for the shuttle to throttle up.

Comment: Also, Saturn V missions from Apollo 14 onwards shut down the center engine considerably earlier than earlier Saturn V missions, in order to avoid the severe pogo oscillations experienced on Apollo 13.

Comment: Citation? I don't remember pogo being an issue for the first stage.