# Do mixture ratio always need to be constant throughout the flight?

Tags: rockets, liquid-fuel

What factors can change the mixture ratio of propellant? I think they can be changed to control the thrust of a rocket.Stay safe.
**EDIT**:What about considering only one stage? Do they change or can they be altered?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27425

Comment: Also related: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41267/6944

Comment: Can you explain what your edit means?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As described in [this QA](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27425/195), the upper stages of the Saturn V could fire their [J-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_J-2) engines at different mixture ratios.

The second stage would switch from 5.5:1 (oxidizer mass to fuel mass) for higher thrust, to 4.5:1 for higher fuel efficiency partway through the ascent.

The third stage would normally start at 4.5:1 and switch to 5:1 partway through the burn, if the trans-lunar injection maneuver was executed at the first opportunity. It was possible to delay it by one orbit, during which time some hydrogen fuel would boil off and be lost; in that case the entire burn would be done at 5:1, which would ensure that a minimum of oxidizer was left unburned when the fuel ran out.

The thrust was about 35% higher at 5.5:1 than at 4.5:1 and the [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) (fuel efficiency) was only a couple of percent lower.

Similar mix ratio controls appear on some other engines (RL10, [RD-180](https://my.fit.edu/~dkirk/4262/RD180_Presentation.pdf)), but I'm not sure how universal they are. Their main use is to balance usage of fuel and oxidizer so you don't end up with a dead-weight surplus of one component or the other at the end of a burn.

Comment: What about considering only one stage? Do they change or can they be altered?

Comment: Yes, in the normal case the second stage would switch from 5.5:1 to 4.5:1, and the third stage would switch from 4.5:1 to 5:1. Edited to clarify.

Comment: OK, but the Saturn V engine design dates back to before the Apple-IIe  :-).    Do modern engines have the capability to adjust flow rates, and is that even more efficient than mixture adjustments?

Comment: I don't know how many modern engines have variable mix ratios; RL10 and RD-180 do, and are in use today. I don't know what distinction you're trying to make between "adjust flow rates" and "mixture adjustments"; it's the same thing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you adjust flow rates while maintaining a constant MR, that's called throttling